# OpenLayers 4 - get resolutions

Tags: openlayers

I want to create combobox with all available scales, that could replace standard zoom slider control. As far as I know, there is no scale attribute in OL and scales must be calculated from resolutions. In api docs I found that resolutions can be retrieved from:

1. view - if fixed resolutions were provided during initialization. In my case they were not and the result is undefined

`var resolutions = this.map.getView().getResolutions();`

2. tileGrid of a layer - I do not have any base layer and for each layer in my map code below does not return resolutions

`resolutions = layers[0].getSource().getTileGrid().getResolutions();`

So now, how can get all available resolutions? I believe I can calculate them from projection but I can't find any proper method to do that.

**EDIT:**

Immediately after posting the question I found a workaround. I can create TileGrid from projecton and get the resolutions from there:

```
var projection = ol.proj.get(this.getSrs());
        var tileGrid = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            extent: projection.getExtent(),
            tileSize: 512
        });

        console.log('projection resolutions', tileGrid.getResolutions());
```

but it does not seem to be good solution, so maybe somone can point me to the right direction.